# Как на C++ записать информацию в файл в котором уже есть текст (его нельзя удалять)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

В обычном .txt файле есть информация и мне необходимо добавить в нее новую не удаляя ту, что была ранее, но при этом так:

```
std::ofstream Fwps("C:\\Jourloy\\Passwords2.txt");
Fwps << text;
Fwps.close();
```

или так:

```
ofstream Fwps;
outFile.open ("C:\\Jourloy\\Passwords2.txt")
Fwps << text;
Fwps.close();
```

или так:

```
ofstream Fwps;
Fwps.open ("C:\\Jourloy\\Passwords2.txt", ios_base::ate)
Fwps << text;
Fwps.close();
```

не получается. Файл очищается. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а почему Вы открываете поток ``std::ofstream file`` а пишите в какой-то ``Fwps `` ?

Comment: Режим открытия надо бы указать... **app**end

Comment: @Александр, ошибка при написании вопроса, одно я писал сам, другое скопировал из редактора. Имя Fwps везде используется.

Comment: @Akina, вы имеете ввиду 'ios_base::app' или я не так понял?

Comment: Именно это я и имею в виду.

Comment: @Akina, сработало, спасибо большое :)